# React Native App Not Running in Simulator 

Tags: ios, react-native, terminal, simulator

So I tried to run my react native app using `react-native run-ios` in Terminal. I even tried using `npx react-native run-ios` for some odd reason. Anyhoo, it only opens the simulator app for me, but my app is not displayed. Am I doing something wrong/is there something I need to install?

Comment: Try to do it directly from XCODE, open the  workspace file inside ios folder. Also if you share the terminal output would be helpful.

Comment: @KarloA.López so here is the Terminal output: ```error Unrecognized command "ios-start". info Run "react-native --help" to see a list of all available commands.```

Comment: @user15009417 you need to use `run-ios` as you said in your question the error suggests you are running `ios-start`